# Stop The Unarchiver from stealing focus

Tags: macos, window-manager

When processing files in the background [The Unarchiver](https://macpaw.com/the-unarchiver) will display a Finder window in front of whatever other app I was using. How do I stop The Unarchiver from stealing focus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To stop The Unarchiver from stealing focus follow these steps:

1. Open The Unarchiver
2. Open the app's preferences
3. Select the Extraction tab
4. Uncheck "Reveal expanded item(s) in Finder"

[image]